# Searching most frequently occurring patterns in a file

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How will you find n most frequently occurring patterns in a text file. What data structures would you use?
Here, a pattern is not a single word but rather a sequence of words. For instance, "this is a" could be a frequently occurring pattern in the file.

Followup questions:

- What if the file is very large (in GBs)?
- What if the file contains text in multiple languages (english, japanese etc)?

PS: I understand that the most frequently occurring words can be found relatively easily using a hash table or BST. Just can't think of how we can find multi-word strings.

Answer (score 5):

One approach to phrase frequency is to use specialized data structures like suffix arrays (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array and if you like academic papers, http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/089120101300346787).

If you have gigabytes of data to index, use hadoop on a big cluster! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching) (prediction by partial matching) or PPM* method of [Cleary and Teahan](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.402&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=SXYsTvqVBMiRswab9eHuCw&usg=AFQjCNEu97t-l4mdI_9GGQ35-SAheohw4w). It is used in text compression. Although you don't need a compression, the very task is the same - find common most sequences of characters in a **very efficient way** using an **efficient data structure**. Look at the paper of Cleary & Teahan above to see how they accomplish this - it is a very good algorithm. I bet there is some open source implementation too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why language matters, except to determining where the word boundaries are. I also assume the patterns are of a certain length? or else the answer is certainly a pattern of length 1 and this is trivial. So why not indeed use a hash table to count all n-grams?

Comment: I think the idea is that n is unknown.  You're trying to find the most common patterns overall, which means that you don't have a fixed value of n to try.

Comment: @Sean: The pattern length is not constant

Comment: @templatetypedef: That's correct. The question was basically to find the most frequent patterns.

Comment: OK, but the pattern "X" will always be at least as common as "X Y" since every occurrence of the latter contains an occurrence of the former. The most frequent pattern will always be length 1. It doesn't sound like that's what the question intended, so that's why I'm wondering if there are unstated requirements.